# is there a possibility to visualize entity-relationship-model of my Wordpress database with phpMyadmin?

Tags: database, wordpress

Something in that way, including the tables created by the different plugins.

https://codex.wordpress.org/images/archive/2/25/20170911181350%21WP4.4.2-ERD.png

Comment: If you can connect to your remote database from your local, then you may use(datagrip) to visualize just like this https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/creating-diagrams.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. I´ve tried mysql workbench so far. But good to know about dg. Maybe I´ll give it a try some other day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a tool like MySQL Workbench (BTW, the screenshot you have provided comes from this tool), to connect to your database and create the diagram like described [here](https://medium.com/@tushar0618/how-to-create-er-diagram-of-a-database-in-mysql-workbench-209fbf63fd03).

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick help Marek. I ve tried Work bench and followed the instructions on your link. So far 'reverse-engeneering' worked out well. I got the tables visualized. But unfortunately the Relation-Lines between the tables are missing. Is it possible to display them as well?

Comment: The lines represent the relations between the tables. They should be visible right away. If I had to guess, I would say that the your schema might be using the MyISAM engine, which does not support Foreign Key relations, thus they are not visible on the diagram (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/myisam-storage-engine.html).

Comment: There is one table using MyISAM, the rest uses InnoDB. But that doesn't change the problem of unsupported foreign key relations, does it?

Comment: It makes me wonder. Do you have Foreign Key relationships between the tables? If yes, then they should appear on the diagram. If not, then no wonder they don't appear. No tool will support this case.  I believe you could check it by reverse engineering the DDL. But also feel free to play with the Workbench and create a schema on your own. Find out when relationships appear and when they do not.